# How to access Contacts in Windows 10 UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to access Contacts Data and so I did some research and found the following article from MSDN

[Accessing Contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/selecting-contacts)

From this article, I read selecting multiple contacts section and I used that but every time, the Emails and Phones value is null.

My code to access contact is below:

```
var contactPicker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
contacts = await contactPicker.PickContactsAsync();

PhoneContactsList.Items.Clear();

if (contacts != null && contacts.Count > 0)
{
    PhoneContactsList.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
    {
        ContactData eachContact = new ContactData();
        eachContact.DisplayName = contact.DisplayName;
        if (contact.Emails.Count > 0)
        {
            eachContact.EmailAddress = contact.Emails[0].Address;
        }
        else if (contact.Phones.Count > 0)
        {
            eachContact.PhoneNumber = contact.Phones[0].Number;
        }
        contactsData.Add(eachContact);
    }
    PhoneContactsList.ItemsSource = contactsData;
}
```

Please suggest what I am doing wrong here?

**Update**

When I debug the code and check I can't see any values, only thing shown is **System._ComObject**. I don't know what it means.

Comment: Did you give access to contacts?

Comment: yes I checked `Contacts` in Capabilities.

Comment: Tried the code sample. Not sure why it gives Null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter contacts by requested fields:

```
var contactPicker = new ContactPicker();
contactPicker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
contactPicker.SelectionMode = ContactSelectionMode.Fields;
contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.PhoneNumber);
contactPicker.DesiredFieldsWithContactFieldType.Add(ContactFieldType.Email);

var contacts = await contactPicker.PickContactsAsync();
if (contacts != null && contacts.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (Contact contact in contacts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(contact.DisplayName + contact.Emails[0].Address);
    }
}
```

p.s. System._ComObject is internal native object. You have to turn on native debugging to work with it.